# C++ Builder AnsiString delete all except < ... >

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe2, c++builder-6, c++builder-xe, c++builder-xe5

I have: `Memo2->Text= IdHTTP1->Get("http://www.twitch.tv/starladder1");`

In Memo2:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' style='overflow: hidden;' xml:lang='en' xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Twitch</title>
<meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
<meta content='app-id=460177396, app-argument=twitch://open' name='apple-itunes-app'>
<meta content='Twitch' name='description'>
<link href='/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'>
<meta content='general' name='rating'>
<meta content='NIH9y45AePyUB62Ur2myinvJOvH77ufgjd6wKiQB6sA' name='google-site-verification'>
<a href='https://plus.google.com/115463106831870703431' rel='publisher'></a>
<meta content='Twitch' property='og:site_name'>
<meta content='161273083968709' property='fb:app_id'>
<meta content='streamname' property='og:title'>
<meta content='STREAM NAME STREAM NAME' property='og:description'>
<meta content='http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/starladder1-profile_image-557367f831a49ebb-600x600.png' property='og:image'>
<meta property='og:url'>
<meta content='video.other' property='og:type'>
<meta content='http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=starladder1&playerType=facebook' property='og:video'>
<meta content='https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=starladder1&playerType=facebook' property='og:video:secure_url'>
<meta content='application/x-shockwave-flash' property='og:video:type'>
<meta content='378' property='og:video:height'>
<meta content='620' property='og:video:width'>`
```

How to delete ALL exept 'STREAM NAME STREAM NAME'. I need Label1->Caption='STREAM NAME STREAM NAME'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site in question is using XHTML, which is compatible with XML, so you can use any XML parser to extract values, like Embarcadero's `TXMLDocument` component or any number of third party parsers (I prefer [libXML2](http://xmlsoft.org) myself).  You are interested in the `content` attribute of the `meta` element whose `property` attribute is `og:description`. Once the XHTML is parsed, you can manually loop through the elements looking at the `property` attributes until you find the one you want, or you can use an XPath query to find that specific element, eg: `/html/head/meta[@property='og:description']`

**Update**: it turns that the site in question is using **malformed** XHTML, so an XML parser will not process it correctly.  So either find a third-party HTML/XHTML parser instead, or just do a simple substring search manually, eg:

```
String Resp = IdHTTP1->Get("http://www.twitch.tv/starladder1");
String StreamName;

int i = Resp.Pos("property='og:description'");
if (i != 0)
{
    i = PosEx("content='", Resp, RPos("<meta ", Resp, i)) + 9;
    StreamName = Resp.SubString(i, PosEx("'", Resp, i) - i);
}
Label1->Caption = StreamName;
```